# Can't stop Apache using homebrew commands

Tags: apache, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I'm building a new web server on a new M1 Mac Mini running the latest version of Big Sur, fresh install. Only thing I have done to the machine is install Chrome.

I'm installing Apache with the following:

- Install xcode command line tools: **xcode-select --install**
- Install Homebrew: **/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL** https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
- Install missing libraries: **brew install openssl**
- Check to see if apache is running, remove any scripts:

  - **sudo apachectl stop**
  - **sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null**
- Install httpd: **brew install httpd**
- Configure autostart: **brew services start httpd**

At this point, httpd is running fine, and I can see the pages at http://localhost:8080

And I can confirm httpd starts up fine after reboot.

Issue is, I can't shut it down. if i issue the command **brew services stop httpd**, I get the following:

> Mac-mini / % brew services stop httpd
> Stopping `httpd`... (might take a while)
> ==> Successfully stopped `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
> Mac-mini / %

Activity monitor still shows multiple instances of httpd running, though.
The only way to shut it down is either quit it in actvity monitor or issue the command

> **sudo apachectl -k stop**

Any suggestions of why niether of the following commands work or how to track down the issue?

> **brew services stop httpd**
> **brew services restart httpd**

Comment: I am two days into this problem with no solution. I've even tried removing MacOS apache2 folder completely incase I had multiple running.

Comment: Removing the LaunchAgent worked for me. `sudo launchctl remove org.apache.httpd`